# How to make responsive full width X full height background-image with text

Tags: html, css, background-image

[image]
I want a webpage with different background-images including text among each other, but think I get stuck in this. Background-images must cover entire width of website and should be responsive. Furthermure Background-images may not overlapping each other as well. Have checked similar questions, but that does not work well for me in this case.

```css
.first-image {
  background-image: url(../Img/-MI4-KK.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: initial;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  background-origin: initial;
  background-clip: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-image">
  <div class="container">
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have found the right answer after some research and effort. Depend on the height of the image I figured out that background-size:cover will affect the  width and height of image that have been shown. Therefore I have replaced that with 100% auto. Furthermore after resizing the screen there was a white space under each image, which was something I would not want to see. In response to that I added padding-bottom of 55% (for someone who is interested how I came to this percentage: 1080 height / 1920 width x 100% = +/- 55%).

```js
.first-image {
 background-image: image 1920 x 1080 A;
 background-size: 100% auto;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 width: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 55%;

}
.second-image {
 background-image: image 1920 x 1080 B;
 background-size: 100% auto;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 width: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 55%;
}

.third-image {
 background-image: image 1920 x 1080 C;
 background-size: 100% auto;
 background-position: 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 width: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 55%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution for you: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GoXpXv

I got rid of the container for you because you didn't define it in your CSS. I created different classes for each of the image sections and have them taking up 100% of the width and 33.333% of the height. I set the body, html and div p margins and padding to 0 so there would be no white space around it. This will adjust to any screen size. Let me know if you have any questions.

HTML:

```
<div class="first-image">
  <p>first image</p>
</div>
<div class="second-image">
  <p>second image</p>
</div>
<div class="third-image">
  <p>third image</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.first-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 33.333%;
  background-image: url(http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.second-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 33.333%;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.photographylife.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Nikon-D810-Image-Sample-6.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.third-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 33.333%;
  background-image: url(http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
div p {
  margin: 0px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Definitely useful, but when I use an image of 1920x1080 the entire image would not have been shown when browser is fully width. If I change height to 100%, the image does not resize at a certain point anymore.